# better way to update a Tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, urllib2

Hi 
so first of all i made a program that downloads music and displays the percent that has downloaded in a list box.

kind of like this

```
    from Tkinter import *
from urllib2 import *
admin = Tk()
Admin = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(admin, bg="PURPLE")
listbox.pack()

def fores():
    chunks = 10000
    dat = ''
    song = '3 rounds and a sound'
    url = 'http://bonton.sweetdarkness.net/music/Blind%20Pilot%20--%203%20Rounds%20and%20A%20Sound.mp3'
    down = urlopen(url)
    downso = 0
    tota = down.info().getheader('Content-Length').strip()
    tota = int(tota)

    while 1:
        a = down.read(chunks)
        downso += len(a)

        if not a:
            break
        dat += a
        percent = float(downso) / tota
        percent = round(percent*100, 1)



        listbox.insert(END, percent)
        listbox.update()
        listbox.delete(0, END)
        listbox.insert(END, percent)
        listbox.update()






button = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=fores)
button.pack()
button = Button(Admin, text='Download', command=fores)
button.pack()
mainloop()
```

I wont show you the original program for it is over the limit of the post size.

On my original program if i move the window before i download an mp3 file it downloads less then 3 % and stops and if i then close the window it starts downloading again.

does anyone know why this is or if there is an alternative to displaying the percentage on the Tkinter window?
Please help

and update_idletasks doesent work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper widget for displaying a string is a [Label](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm). You can change the text at runtime with the `configure` method:

```
self.progress = Label(...)
...
self.progress.configure(text="%s%% completed" % percent)
```

Second, you are creating two root windows - `admin` and `Admin`. And strangely, you are putting the listbox in one and the buttons in another. Tk isn't designed to work like that. Third, you need to call the mainloop method of your (single) root window (eg: `Admin.mainloop`)

Finally, as to your comment that `update_idletasks` doesn't work -- please define "doesn't work". It will in fact update the display. What it won't do is let you interact with the window while it is running.

I made changes to your code based on the above comments (created only one root, used a `Label` rather than `Listbox`, and used `update_idletasks` and the program ran to completion, downloading the song.

The danger of calling `update` is this: what if you click the "download" button while you are already downloading? What happens is the next time `update` is called, that button press will be serviced. In the servicing of that event you'll enter an infinite loop. While that inner infinite loop is running the outer one cannot run. You will have effectively frozen the first download.

The proper solution involves one of (at least) two techniques. One, create a thread to do the downloading, and have it periodically send information back to the main loop so it can update the progress bar. The second is to leverage the already existing infinite loop -- the event loop -- and do your reading of chunks one at a time by placing jobs on the event queue with `after`.

There are examples on the internet for both approaches.

Answer (score -1):

i use a ttk.Progressbar, all you have to do is associate a variable to it and update that particular variable.

http://docs.python.org/library/ttk.html#progressbar

http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/morewidgets.html#progressbar